# In German localization, use submenu label "Extras" for typical "Tools" submenu?

Tags: menu, localization

Main menu bar like

```
File    Edit   View   Tools   Help
```

was a tradition in Microsoft Windows and often still is. But in German localization, I have often seen `Extras` in place of `Tools`.

**Is it appropriate to use `Werkzeuge` (translation of `Tools`) in German or keep that semantically different `Extras`?**

If you have experience with German applications, is menu item `Extras` sounding natural and `Werkzeuge` disturbing?

Answer (score 1):

The semantic is actually different.
For example a painting program:

**Werkzeuge** may be:

- brusch
- knife
- pencil
- color chooser
- ...

**Extras** may be:

- always on top (functionality)
- **Werkzeuge** (possibly, but also useable as menu item)
- presetting
- default options
- ...

Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You're correct - although the same could be said about the English term *tools*. Possibly, *tools* can just be considered on too many abstraction levels and thus isn't the best term in the first place (although *Extras*, of course, is hardly any better than *Others* or *Random stuff*).